# Addition and Subtraction with Negative Numbers

Tags: javascript, html, negative-number

I tried adding and subtracting negative numbers with this code

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.form1.num1.value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.form1.num2.value);
if(operand == "plus"){
    var sum = parseInt(num1+num2);
    // add alerts to check
    alert (num1);
    alert (num2);
    alert (sum);
}else{
    var sum = parseInt(num1-num2);
}
```

but when I print the result (sum), the program ignore the negative number and just count it as if it's a positive number. I tried delete the parseInt but nothing changes.
for those who's confused : my inputs are num1 and num2. using the code I had, if I input (4) and (-2) and choose plus sign, sum = 6. they dont count the negative as negative, but as positive.

update : apparently even if I input (-2), they save it as (2).

Comment: What are `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: try:  var sum = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2);

Comment: parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2) wont work if I have 2 negative numbers.

Comment: @jack , if I choose plus sign, and input 4 and 5, the sum will be 9. and if I choose minus and input 6 and 2, the sum is 4. there's nothing wrong with the branch.

Comment: Well, `parseInt("4" + "-2")` gives `4` and `parseInt(4-2)` gives `2`; but definitely not `6` ...

Comment: Do you realise that if you subtract a negative number it gives the same result as adding the same number's absolute value? Example: `-4 - -9 = 5 = -4 + 9`.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLza8wna/1/).

Comment: Or in more general terms: `x - -y = x + y`

Comment: @jack this code supposed to be working as well....

Comment: @HikmahAz What code? You've shared a snippet that I've put into a working example; it's your task to either find out the differences or share more code.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it was my own fault. I put the order of codes wrong. thanks everyone who offered help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sum1 and sum2 are string literals, what you should do is `parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)`

It seems your problem is that you're applying a double negative, which makes a positive:

```
4 - -2 == 4 + 2
```